# Connect to IBM DB2 on Cloud using python api ibm_db

Tags: python, db2, ibm-cloud

Can you please let me know how to connect to DB2 on IBM Cloud using python?

I have tried the below steps.

1. installed ibm_db using `pip install ibm_db`
2. Created a free tier Db2 service on IBM cloud
3. Generated Service credentials key
4. Trying to establish a connection with the database with the credential details (Database, host, port, user id, and password) extracted from the Service credentials key

```
import ibm_db

print("Creating connection.......")

conn_string = "DATABASE=bludb;HOSTNAME=54a2f15b-5c0f-46df-8954-7e38e612c2bd.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud;PORT=32733;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<userId>;PWD=<password>;"

conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_string,"","")
if conn:
    print("Connection ...... [SUCCESS]")
else:
    print("Connection ...... [FAILURE]")
```

I am getting below error message:

> SQLCODE=-30082n: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "17" ("UNSUPPORTED FUNCTION"). SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: Please provide details on the type of credentials you have. Do they already include a database URI for SSL? Use that as input to your connect command. `ibm_db.connect(ssldsn, "", "")`

Comment: The port and hostname details I got from the service credentials key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you are on the [new Db2 on Cloud lite plan](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-faq_lite) with non-standard ports and SSL enforced. When you connect to Db2 using the Python driver and use SSL, you have to add the `SECURITY=SSL` property, e.g.:

```
conn_string = "DATABASE=bludb;HOSTNAME=yourhostname;PORT=<port>;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=<userId>;PWD=<password>;SECURITY=SSL"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way to do this is with **SQL Magic**. This way, you can just type a SQL statement just by adding %sql before your query

First install the packages

```
!pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.9
!pip install ibm_db_sa
```

Then,

```
%load_ext sql
```

Finally, run the following code by replacing your username, password, hostname and SSL. You can find these in your IBM DB2 under credentials.

```
%sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@hostname:port/BLUDB?security=SSL
```

Now you can run any SQL by using %sql before or %%sql if the whole cell is going to be SQL. Example:

```
%sql SELECT * FROM TABLENAME;
```

or

```
%%sql 
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a python package called `ibm_db`, does [this link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=db-connecting-database-server) or (cited in the first one) [this one](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs) help?

Comment: I'm trying with ibm_db package but getting below error
```
SQLCODE=-30082n: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "17" ("UNSUPPORTED FUNCTION").  SQLSTATE=08001
```

Comment: Hi jkafrouni and Welcome to SO, from my point of view this is a comment, it's not an answer. Please check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @mao I have added the code snippet that I'm trying in the question. Can you please check and let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: @Carmoreno indeed, meant to create a comment since I knew this wasn't a complete answer :) my bad!